# Product Notation Formulas/Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I tackle this problem?

Find a formula for the sequence: $d$ defined by:
$$d_n= \prod^n_{i=1}b_i$$

Where:
$$b_n= n(-1)^n$$

Comment: As I commented on a recent question you asked, please [format your posts with MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It's almost impossible to tell what you're trying to write here.

Comment: Hi Joey, and welcome to Math.SE!  As @T.Bongers has pointed out, we have a great math formatting markup language for writing out math formulae.  I've attempted to edit your post to use this markup, but I could have made a mistake--does the post currently reflect your intent?  You learn more about how the formatting works by clicking "edit post" to see the code that I used.

Comment: Regarding the question: What (specifically) do you not understand about the question?  Do you know what the product notation means?  Have you tried anything, or have any thoughts/"hunches" about the problem on which you'd like feedback?  The more you tell us about your specific question, the better we can help you. :)

Comment: The question is written properly. I'm confused on how exactly to rewrite this given the bn function. I just dont understand logically what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Write out the first few products:

$$d_1 = b_1 = -1$$

$$d_2 = b_1 b_2 = (2)(-1) = -2$$

$$d_3 = b_1 b_2 b_3 = (-3)(2)(-1) = 3\cdot 2 \cdot 1$$

$$d_4 = (4)(-3)(2)(-1) = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$$

$$d_5 = -5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$$

Can you try writing something involving factorials and appropriate powers of $(-1)$?

Comment: I understand what you have here but how do you know the limitations if its n??

Comment: @joey What do you mean by "limitations"? Do you see the pattern involving $d_n$ and $n!$?

Comment: That you used the factorial yes, I see that. I don't understand how to effectively get the formula? is the upper limitation just n! ?

Comment: @joey What do you mean by "upper limitation"?

Comment: The upper limitation, the value above the product notation. (n). i=1 is the lower limitation. So I'm confused on how to translate these into a sequence and work backwards.

Comment: @joey The upper limit for $d_n$ is just $n$, according to the definition you wrote.

Comment: Right, which is why im totally confused on how we answer the question and find the formula

Comment: @joey I wrote out the first 5 terms of the sequence. Can you write down a closed form involving $n!$ and powers of $(-1)$ to generate this same sequence? My answer is meant to be a hint, and then you can fill in all the details.

Comment: I'm sorry I must be missing the concept here cause I just don't get it. If we have n! (n*n*n etc), and powers of (-1), how can we generate -1, -2, 6, 24....?  -1*1, -1*2, -1*-6? -1* -24?